# Ldap SASL with unboundID

Tags: java, android

I am developing  an android app in which using unboundedID.jar I have implemented SSL TLS
but no idea about SASL can you give me some idea. Some sample code.How to implement SASL with 
unbound id

Answer (score 2):

The UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java supports a number of SASL mechanisms, including:

- ANONYMOUS (which really doesn't perform any meaningful authetication)
- CRAM-MD5 and DIGEST-MD5 (password-based mechanisms which use cryptographic digests to protect the password)
- EXTERNAL (using something the server knows about the client outside of LDAP communication, like an SSL/TLS certificate)
- GSSAPI (using Kerberos V)
- PLAIN (using a username and password)

It also includes a generic SASL bind support, which allows you to specify the mechanism and supply pre-encoded credentials if they are needed.

For all of the mechanisms that are explicitly supported, the javadoc includes an example demonstrating how to use it (e.g., the ANONYMOUSBindRequest class provides support for the SASL ANONYMOUS mechanism, and it includes a simple example that shows how to use it).

Unfortunately, though, Android doesn't support some of the APIs that the LDAP SDK needs for full SASL support.  In particular, the UnboundID LDAP SDK's implementations of the CRAM-MD5, DIGEST-MD5, and GSSAPI mechansisms will not work on Android.  However, the ANONYMOUS, EXTERNAL, and PLAIN mechanisms should work just fine on Android.  The generic SASL API should also work if you're willing to do the credential encoding and decoding yourself.

Comment: As I mentioned in my reply, the Javadoc documentation for the classes providing this capability all include examples that demonstrate how to use them.  For example, http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html?com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/PLAINBindRequest.html has an example that demonstrates how to use the LDAP SDK in order to perform a SASL PLAIN bind.  You can also look at the source for the com.unboundid.util.SASLUtils class to see how it constructs various kinds of SASL bind requests.

Comment: Hi,In my Ldap application I have to implement Digest-Md5 and genric sasl mechanism on Android.When I am using unbound classes & methods its throwing method not supported exception.I search allot but not find any useful solution.If some one have idea.How to do it on android?Is it possible on android?If it is then how i will implement.Please provide me solution. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: As I mentioned in my original response, the version of Java that Android provides doesn't include SASL support that the LDAP SDK relies on for CRAM-MD5, DIGEST-MD5, or GSSAPI.  This means that you can't use the LDAP SDK's support for these SASL mechanisms on Android.  That isn't to say that it's completely impossible to make DIGEST-MD5 work on Android, but it does mean that you'd have to do all the encoding and decoding and cryptography yourself.  That's not a trivial amount of work, which is why the LDAP SDK relies on the support Java provides for it.